# How to put functions into Rserve workspace?

Tags: r, tableau-api, workspace, rserve

I try to use Rserve from Tableau. I am able to execute the following code:

```
SCRIPT_REAL(".arg1*.arg2", MAX([Price]), [TestParam])
```

Basically, I write the R code in Tableau (`".arg1*.arg2"` in my case) and send it to Rserve. Rserve, in its turn, takes the code, executes it and sends the result back to Tableau.

Now I am trying to do the same but by defining a function within R environment and accessing it from Tableau via Rserve. So, I execute the following in R:

```
> myfunc <- function(x, y) {x*y}
> library(Rserve)
> Rserve()
```

Which means that I define a function in R environment and then start Rserve in the same environment with the hope that Rserve will see the function that I have defined before.

Then in Tableau I define a new column using this code:

```
SCRIPT_REAL("myfunc(.arg1,.arg2)", MAX([Price]), [TestParam])
```

As you can see, I try to call the function (`myfunc`) that I have defined in R.

As a result I get an error message that tells me that `myfunc` is not found.

By exploring web a bit I found that it is to expect since functions defined in R work-space are not in the work-space of Rserve. So, my question is: **Is it possible to define a function in R and then make it visible to Rserver so that Rserve can serve these functions?**

Comment: I'm not an Rserve guru, but I'm guessing you'll need to turn it into a package and have it installed in a system-library (not under `$HOME`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to define a function in R and then make it visible to Rserver so that Rserve can serve these functions?

Of course it is.  You "just" tell Rserve to

- source a file with functions (not recommended, read on)
- load one or more libraries as needed (recommended, also for local code)

just as you would *with any other R session* because that is what Rserver offers: headless R sessions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need to admit that I am very new to R. So, I do not know how to "tel" Rserve to. In particular, how to source a file with the function or how to put my function into my library. Is it hard to create my own (local) library?

Comment: It is not, but asking in a comment is not the best way to learn. I just googled 'how to create an R package', got 140 million (hits) including the key bullet points of a popular tutorial.  It is something worth learning.  There are also hundreds of related questions (and answers!) here.

Comment: Before I wrote my comment I googled too and I found a pdf with 19 pages. The reason I wrote the comment is that I assume (hope) that there is just one "magic" command (one line of code) with which I can source my file (or create a library) and everything will work. And if it is the case, I think it makes sense to ask about it here. Especially taken into account that I am under time pressure and have not time to read 20 pages document (unfortunately).

Comment: Yes. the magic single command is `library(mypackage)`.  And yes, it expects you to learn how to write a library such that things work magically and reliably.  That is what you're after, no?

Comment: I actually went for the first options (sourcing a file with the function) since it looks easier to implement. I tried to source before importing and starting Rserve. I also put `source C:\Users\myname\Documents\test.R` into the `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\library\Rserve\libs\x64\Rserve.cfg` file. It does not work either.

Comment: Looks easier, but doesn't work (as reliably). **There is a reason we recommend packages instead.** Anyway, I don't have time to personally tutor you here not is the place.  Please read some documentation, then maybe ask a new question.